# Java BigDecimal is rounding necessary with addition?

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I am working with `BigDecimal` and I know that if I divide I have to use `MathContext` and tell which `Scale` and `RoundingMode` to avoid `ArithmeticException` as described in the documentation:

> In the case of divide, the exact quotient could have an infinitely
>   long decimal expansion; for example, 1 divided by 3. If the quotient
>   has a nonterminating decimal expansion and the operation is specified
>   to return an exact result, an ArithmeticException is thrown.

In the method I'm working on I have to sum amounts coming from our database (that are rounded at 2 decimals) with amounts coming from an external service, and I don't know the exact scaling of these amounts (probabily 3 decimals).

My question is, can I trust `BigDecimal`'s add method and use it without rounding and scaling or it's a good practice to always specify the desired scale?

Is there any particular case in which addition and subtraction can raise `ArithmeticException`?

Comment: Did you actually read the documentation for the add method? It clearly states that if you do not define a scale itself it will use the maximum scale off the 2 operands. So "1.123+3" will use a scale of 3 for the result by default, which is all you need for total precision.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS yes I have read it, but I really want to be sure and I still have doubt about this. And I'm curious to know if it's good practice to always use rounding or not. Seems a reasonable question to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BigDecimal.add()` will throw `ArithmeticException` if the scale of the result does not fit into an `int`.

A simple example is adding two numbers with the maximum and the minimum scales:

```
BigDecimal a = new BigDecimal(BigInteger.ONE, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal(BigInteger.ONE, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
a.add(b);
```

If your application needs to operate at such *scale* then you probably have some *bigger* problems than worrying about arithmetic exception.

Adding numbers without using `MathContext` will maintain proper scale and give you the precice result. Depending on the actual values this approach can use arbitrary amount of memory to represent increasingly long numbers, and longer numbers take more time to add.

Adding numbers without using `MathContext` and rouding once after the summation will give you the precice result rounded to the requested `MathContext`. The memory and computation costs are the same as in the first case.

Using `MathContext` for each addition will produce a result which can differ from the presize result by an arbitrary value, but the memory and speed will be more predicatable.

Choosing which one of these approaches to use really depends on the nature of the task, so it is up to you to assess and chose the proper approach for each particular case.